# Comparison of time to thermal equilibrium

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium

I suddenly got curious in real life.

The refrigerator stops working when it reaches a set temperature.

If a hot object enters the refrigerator, the temperature of the refrigerator will rise and it will start working again.

Suppose you have two objects that have exactly the same physical properties.(Let's say object A, object B.)

The refrigerator is in thermal equilibrium according to the set temperature.

The question itself is very simple, but I'm not sure if it's an answer to how to model and solve it.

The question is this.

When objects A and B are placed in the refrigerator at the same time, the time it took to achieve thermal equilibrium is called t1

Let's say t2 is the time it took to get back to thermal equilibrium when we put object A first and then we put object B right away.

**Can you tell me which one has a larger value, t1 or t2?**

My intuition tells me that t2 has a larger value, but it's hard to prove because I don't have much physical knowledge.

Is there anyone who can help me with this problem?

I'm looking forward to hearing from some great physicists. Thank you!

Comment: Are you assuming the idealized situation in which the air of the room and the time during which the door is open have no effect?  by "right away", do you mean zero seconds after object A is placed or zero seconds after object A reaches equilibrium?  Also, are you considering that any noticeable time passes during the placement of object A?

Comment: @KenMellendorf sorry for confusing. yes you are right. There is no heat loss when opening and closing the door, and there is no heat loss from the inside to the outside of the refrigerator. The meaning of "right away" means putting in B right away without any delay in time.